# Sorting subarray by lastname

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I have sorted by year within which I have arrays with a lastname key. I am looking to sort these subarrays by lastname.

I managed to classify by year. But the arrays inside are not sorted by lastname.

```
[
    "1946" => [
        [
            "firstname" => "Juan",
            "lastname" => "Darcy"
        ], [
            "firstname" => "Franck",
            "lastname" => "Bolly"
        ]
    ],
    "1945" => [
        [
            "firstname" => "Pierre",
            "lastname" => "Carry"
        ], [
            "firstname" => "Catherine",
            "lastname" => "Aarron"
        ]
    ]
]
```

I would to reorder array by lastname without changing the order of the years, like that :

```
[
    "1946" => [
        [
            "firstname" => "Franck",
            "lastname" => "Bolly"
        ], [
            "firstname" => "Juan",
            "lastname" => "Darcy"
        ]
    ],
    "1945" => [
        [
            "firstname" => "Catherine",
            "lastname" => "Aarron"
        ], [
            "firstname" => "Pierre",
            "lastname" => "Carry"
        ]
    ]
]
```

I tried this:

```
$alumnis_array_number = [];
foreach ($alumnis_array_year as $value) {
    $year = $value['year'];
    $alumnis_array_number[$year][] = $value;
}

uasort($alumnis_array_number, function($a, $b) {
    return strcasecmp($a['lastname'], $b['lastname']);
});
```

But I got

> Undefined index: lastname

How can I get those subarrays sorted by lastname?

Comment: Doesn't `[lastname]` mean it is in an array?

Comment: How do you generate this array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems easier to perform the sort *before* you group the data by year. So you would sort `$alumnis_array_year` before executing the code you quoted in your question:

```
uasort($alumnis_array_year, function($a, $b) {
    $diff = $b["year"] - $a["year"];
    if ($diff) return $diff;
    $diff = strcasecmp($a['lastname'], $b['lastname']);
    if ($diff) return $diff;
    return strcasecmp($a['firstname'], $b['firstname']);
});
```

If you do this first and then execute your code, it will be OK.

Comment: I didn't know I had to do this before. Thank you very much for your help. The code works perfectly